# Looping through x number of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I loop through x number of arrays and visit all combinations of all cells in all of the arrays? The problem here is there can be x number of arrays of some items inside. For instance,

```
List<List<string>> _arrays = GetArrayInformation();
```

I want to compare all the string inside each array with all the other arrays and the strings inside of each array. Do I use while like

```
while(i < _arrays.Count)
```

Thanks for your answer. The answer seems simple but when you think about it is kind of tricky and hard.

Update:

Thanks for your answers. I can do this with a 3 arrays like

```
for(int i = 0; i < _arrays[0].Count; i++) {
 for(int l = 0; l < _arrays[1].Count; l++) {
  for(int m = 0; m < _arrays[2].Count; m++) {
    string _hello = _arrays[0][i] + "|" + _arrays[1][l] + "|" + _arrays[2][m];
  }
 }
}
```

Because I have dynamic number of arrays, it gets tricky.

Comment: Your want the result to be `List<List<String>>`? What does that represent? What do you mean by *I want to compare all the strings inside each array with each other*. Compare how?

Comment: Compare all elements in an array with all the other arrays' elements. I want to find what string appears in another array's elements. I don't want to just loop through every single element in every array individually. I want to match a specific element with another array's element.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var array in _arrays)
{
   foreach(var s in array) 
   {
       foreach(var otherArray in _arrays)
       {
           if(otherArray == array) continue;
           if(otherArray.Contains(s)) {}  // not sure what you want to do
       }
   }
}
```

this will loop through every single string seeing if it is in any other array.... it's the straightforward approach, but not very efficient and will duplicate work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no enough information is here

If you need to find elements that exists in few array You will use something like this:

```
var multipleWords = _arrays
    .SelectMany(items => items.Distinct())
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(group => new {Item = group.Key, Count = group.Count()})
    .Where(item => item.Count > 1)
    .Select(item => item.Item)
    .ToArray();
```

multipleWords will contain each word from the all these arrays that exists in two or more arrays

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive search function.

```
   public Search<T>(object o, string comparestring)
   {
         if(o is List<string>)
         {
         //Compare to your string
         }
         else
         {
             //Call this search function with the type of the object in the list.
             //Will iterate through all of your strings recursively.
             Type t = o.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
             foreach( object osub in (T)o)
                 Search<t>( ((t)o),comparestring)
         }

    }
```